# TCP connection - strings are recieved mixed

Tags: java, c#, tcp

I have a TCP server in Java and a client in C#. The connection already exists and a few messages can be sent, but when I am writing many messages to the server I receive when the stream is closing something like that

`LOCATION|015|0LOCATION|014,99163|0LOCATION|014,89123|0LOCATION|014,81594|0LOCATION|014,78247|0LOCATION|014,74063|0LOCATION|014,69043|0LOCATION|014,63187|0LOCATION|014,56493|0LOCATION|014,56493|0LOCATION|014,3976|0LOCATION|014,3976|0LOCATION|014,2972|0LOCATION|014,18843|0LOCATION|014,0713|0LOCATION|0,000219846914,07641|-0,000412796LOCATION|0,000259`

in one line, instead of `LOCATION|UniversumGames|double;double;double` in one line.
Can please somebody help?
P.S.the Client cannot be wrong, because i used the same like in my twitchbot....

Server code (Java):

```
public void run(){
    try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        out.println("Connected");
        out.flush();
        out.write("Connected 1");
        out.flush();

        while(socket.isConnected()){
            String line = in.readLine();
            //String line = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            if(line != null){
                CommandController.control(new Data(line), socket);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client Code(c#):

```
private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    private StreamReader reader;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private bool recieve;


    public ClientConnection()
    {
        this.recieve = true;
        this.tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 2700);
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
        // use the ipaddress as in the server program

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        this.stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        this.writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        this.reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

        this.writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine("Connected clientside sucessful");
        writer.WriteLine("Connected clientside sucessful 1");
        writer.WriteLine("Connected clientside sucessful 2");
        writer.WriteLine("Connected clientside sucessful 3");
    }

    public async void Recieve()
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>RecieveString());
    }

    public string RecieveString()
    {
        this.recieve = true;
        while (recieve)
        {
            //if (stream.DataAvailable)
            //{
                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                if (data != null)
                {
                writer.WriteLine(data + " recieved");
                writer.Flush();
                    return data;
                }
                else return "";
            //}   
            //else return "";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: The c# you posted isn't valid code, in and out are reserved keywords. It looks more like Java. Now that I look closer, it seems you posted the Java code twice.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i helped myself...

```
String line = "1";
while(line != null) {
            byte size = dataInputStream.readByte();
            byte[] buf = new byte[size];
            dataInputStream.read(buf, 0, size);
            line = new String(buf);

        }
```

that´s the better way for the while-loop in the server...
and i found out that I´m sending messages in different Threads from the client, that could explain why the string is mixed...